# Best java API for distance functions

Tags: java, distance

I am new to this kind of computing. I don't know what are the existing distance functions that are helpful to calculate the distance between to double sets(arrays). Can some one suggest me at-least 10 distance functions so that i can select few among them which suits best for my problem domain. I just want to calculate the distance between two sets for my scientific approach to the problem domain. I also want to know whether i have to implement them manually or any java API that covers most distance functions? Suggestions can help me to minimize my effort and save my time..:)

Comment: Look for Java Physics engines like [JBullet](http://jbullet.advel.cz/) or [ODE4J](http://ode4j.sourceforge.net/) or [Simpull](http://code.google.com/p/simpull/) or just google for more. These should have everything you need. the only time I needed to calculate distance I just personally wrote the functions.

Comment: @user896456: your *"scientific approach"* doesn't look very scientific ; )

Answer (score 1):

Providing you with code is not really going to help.  What you need to do is to read up on the mathematics of the the various measures of distance, and figure out which is most appropriate based on *that knowledge*.

You could start by reading the Wikipedia page on [Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance) and the linked pages and resources.

Only when you've decide on an appropriate measure do you need to go looking for code.  In a lot of cases, it is probably simplest to implement the measure yourself.

---

Alternatively, if you want us to provide sensible suggestions of measures that are appropriate to your problem domain, tell us what the problem domain is.

Comment: thanks for your response. Here is my problem domain. From real numbers space i can choose two sets of size n elements. Each set contains n real numbers. Instead directly choosing one distance function and saying the simillarity between two sets i want to find the nature of sets and apply appropriate distance function to find the distance between them. So that the space s can be divided to groups of sets on basis of distance functions. In future if i want to find the distance between two new sets from the same space i can directly find the distance equation that suits best for pair.

Comment: That's not a description of a problem domain.  That's just a restatement of your original abstract requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about statistical distance between two samples? If so, there is an abundance of methods, each one suiting a different problem.

If your problem domain is simple, subtracting the sample means (averages) could suffice. For more complex data, the Earth Movers' Distance is common, though newer and more robust methods (such as kernel functions) are available.

Coding is the least of your problems. You must provide a more accurate definition of your problem before I can further assist you.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I replied to stephen and commented my problem domain. I hope you understand what i mean .if not i will try to do the same in more specific way in my next comment.